# multi threads with audio

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i have `classA` that has a callback audio function, he calls many many times to `class B` function, and give it as argument the audio level.

problem is that it happens so many times a second so i get this :

```
class __NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
```

i know i need to set one of this class to be in another thread, with :

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(setMovement:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

but i dont know how exactly i do that , and where to put that line(what class).
i have tried put it in class B init , but still get that warnning.

on the iphone its crash, on simulation its working.
only if i reduce the number of calls ,i can put it on the device.

how exactly do i set this thread, and to which class ?
(classes are scenes in cocos2d-but i dont think thats matter)

thanks a lot/

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your post what are the roles of class A and class B. I hope I understand it right, that your class-A's code repeatedly calls classB method, in some audio context.

I also guess here, that the source of those calls IS NOT your code, but rather some system call, or some external call from the audio system.

In that case, It might be that the audio calls originate in a context of some thread, that has no autorelease pool. When you write your code in the class-B method, you probably create autoreleased object (such as [NSString stringWithFormat:@"….",…]) and these leak, because there is no autorelease pool to handle them.

Here I'm not sure why you though you should detach a new thread --- If your problem is the leak, all you need to do is to enclose the Class-B method contents in an @autoreleasepool {….} scope. That would help releasing all the autoreleased objects.

something like

```
@implementation classB
// this is the method being repeatedly called from class A's audio function
-(void)callbackImplementation:(NSInteger)voiceLevel {
    @autorelease {
    // put all your code here.
    }
    return;
}
@end
```